# Remainder , product of two factors

Tags: polynomials

Polynomial function $P(x)$ satisfies that

$P(x) = (x+1)^3 Q_1 (x) + 2x^2 +1$

$P(x) = (x-1)^3 Q_2 (x) + 24x^2 -32x +19$

$P(1) = 11,  P(-1)=3$

$P(x) = (x+1)^3 (x-1)^3 Q_3 (x) + R(x)  $

Find $R(x)$  .

I thought of comparing the next two expressions
$R(x) = (x+1)^3(ax^2 +bx+c ) +2x^2 +1 = (x-1) ^3 (a x^2 + dx+e ) + 24x^2 -32x +19$

but hard to find each coefficient.

Comment: "$P(1) = 11,  P(-1)=3$" $\;\;$ That's a good starting point. Maybe you can find $\,P'(1),P'(-1)\,$ next.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness @dxiv, but I want to solve without Calculus.

Comment: If "$P(1) = 11,  P(-1)=3$" is a hypothesis, it is redundant with the two previous lines.

Comment: Apply the Chinese remainder theorem. You are given the remainder of $P$ modulo two coprime polynomials, you can derive its remainder modulo their product.

Comment: Looks Like $R(x)=(x-1)^j(x+1)^k$ for $j$ and $ k > 0.$

Comment: After knowing Bezout's equation , finally I can solve it. thank you, @Anne Bauval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question can be rewritten like this:

Given a polynomial $P(x)$ that satisfies:

$$
\begin{cases}
P(x) \equiv 2x^2 + 1 \mod{(x+1)^3} \\
P(x) \equiv 24x^2 - 32x + 19 \mod{(x-1)^3}
\end{cases}
$$

Find $R(x)$ such that:
$$
P(x) \equiv R(x) \mod{((x+1)^3(x-1)^3)}
$$

Chinese remainder theorem can solve this system of congruence just like in integer modulo arithmetic (See [Chinese remainder theorem](https://brilliant.org/wiki/chinese-remainder-theorem/)). This only works if the moduli are pairwise coprime, in this case we can verify that $(x+1)^3$ and $(x-1)^3$ are coprime using Euclidean algorithm. If we set up variables like this ($A^{-1} \mod{B}$ denotes the modulo multiplicative inverse of A with respect
to modulus B):
$$
\begin{cases}
a_1 = 2x^2 + 1 \\
a_2 = 24x^2 - 32x + 19 \\
y_1 = (x-1)^3 \\
y_2 = (x+1)^3 \\
z_1 \equiv [(x-1)^3]^{-1} \mod{(x+1)^3} \\
z_2 \equiv [(x+1)^3]^{-1} \mod{(x-1)^3}
\end{cases}
$$
then the solution will be:
$$
R(x) \equiv a_1y_1z_1 + a_2y_2z_2 \mod{((x+1)^3(x-1)^3)}
$$
By using extended Euclidean's algorithm, we can find one solution of $z_1$ and $z_2$:
$$
z_1 = \frac{-3}{16}x^2 - \frac{9}{16}x - \frac{1}{2}
$$
$$
z_2 = \frac{3}{16}x^2 - \frac{9}{16}x + \frac{1}{2}
$$
Distributing everything, we have:
$$
R(x) \equiv \frac{33}{8}x^7 - 6x^6 - \frac{83}{8}x^5 + 20x^4 + \frac{75}{8}x^3 - 17x^2 + \frac{7}{8}x + 10 \mod{((x+1)^3(x-1)^3)} 
$$
or equivalently:
$$
R(x) \equiv 2x^5 + 2x^4 - 3x^3 + x^2 + 5x + 4 \mod{((x+1)^3(x-1)^3)} 
$$

Comment: Thank you for you kindness . But I want to solve using two initial condition, and to teach for high school students.

Comment: Hmm not sure how to do that, but you should've added it in the post so people would know what you're looking for.